# Calling server side function with parameter from Javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, cross-site

I have an **ASP.NET** application in **VB.NET**. I have a **Javascript** function in `mypage.aspx` and another one in my `callback.aspx` page. I need this scripts to render and submit an `IFrame` on `mypage.aspx`.

When I click on the submit button:

```
<asp:Button ID="subbtn" Name="Submit" OnClientClick="onsubmit_action();" runat="server" />
```

this script is executed, where `iframeId` is the id of the `IFrame`:

```
function onsubmit_action() {

            submitPage('iframeId');           
        }
```

The response of the `IFrame` (validation or success) is submitted to the `callback.aspx` file. I guess this happens through **cross-site scripting** that calls the callback function in the `callback.aspx` file;

```
function callback()
{
     parent.pagecallback_success('<%=Request.QueryString("Id")%>');
}
```

that calls the function in `mypage.aspx`

```
function pagecallback_success(ref_id) {
        var Url = "mypage.aspx?";
        Url += "id=" + id;
        window.location.href = Url;
    }
```

The script works as expected. Now, I would like to call a server function

```
Protected Function Store(ByVal id As String) As Boolean
```

in `mypage.aspx.vb` and pass the variable `id`:

```
function hostedpagecallback_success(id) {
            var Url = "mypage.aspx?";
            Url += "id=" + id;
            window.location.href = Url;
            "<%= Store(id) %>"
        }
```

The problem is that the compiler considers `id` as a server side function and gives a compile error. However if I use a `sub` (without parameters) instead of a function, the `sub` is executed 3 times, on `page_load`, when the `IFrame` is received and another time (connection is https cannot debug **Javascript** efficiently).

I am not good in cross-site scripting and code nuggets, probably it is really trivial but I do not know how to solve this problem. Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for page methods a feature of MS-Ajax.  Put the [WebMethod]
 on the method you want to call (server side) and call it client side with something like PageMethods.GetData(f, s, OnRequestComplete, OnRequestError);

The whole pattern takes an article to describe.
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article454-using-pagemethods-and-json-in-aspnet-ajax.aspx